# Apache Mina SSHD Server - How to get the list of forwarded ports

Tags: sshd, apache-mina

I have built a server/client system with Apache Mina SSHD.
Clients connect the server by creating a session. Then they request port forwarding:

```
session.startRemotePortForwarding(ssaRemote,ssaLocal);
```

What I need is that: In server side, I should be able to tell which client's which port is forwarded to server's which port.

For example, if the client A requested a remote forwarding between its port 12345 and server's port 67890; and client B requested a remote forwarding between its port 11111 and server's port 22222; I need a list like:

- ClientA 67890
- ClientB 22222